# Creating a Review Rails Backend/React Frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, fetch

I am attempting to allow a user that is logged in to create a review for a game.  I am having a couple issues that keep popping up in my console.

```
HTTP Origin header (http://localhost:3001) didn't match request.base_url (http://localhost:3000)
```

I attempted to remedy this with putting `config.force_ssl = true` in my production file from what I read up on, but still hitting this issue.

Im also hitting

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
```

which is ref my review_controller in create

```
app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb:19:in `create'
```

Below is my ReviewController and my ReviewContainer and ReviewForm

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
    # before_action :authorized, only:[:create]
    before_action :authenticate_with_http_digest, only: [:new, :create]

    def index
        reviews = Review.all
        render json: reviews
    end

    def show
        review = Review.find_by(params[:id])
        render json: review
    end

    def create
        game = Game.find_or_create_by(name: params[:review][:game_name])
        review = Review.new(review_params)
        review.game_id = game.id
        review.user_id = @user.id
        review.save
        render json: review
    end

    def update
        review = Review.find(params[:id])
        review.update(review_params)
        review.save
        render json: review
    end

    def destroy
        review = Review.find(params[:id])
        review.destroy
        render json: {error: "Review Removed"}
    end
    private
    def review_params
        params.require(:review).permit(:user_id, :game_id, :user_username, :reviewed_game, :rating, :game_name)
    end
end
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Review from './Review'
import ReviewForm from './ReviewForm'

export default class ReviewsContainer extends Component {

  state = {
    reviews: [],
}

componentDidMount(){
fetch('http://localhost:3000/reviews')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(reviews => this.setState({ reviews }))
}
            
  addReview = (review) => {
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/reviews',{
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
              "Content-Type" : "application/json",
              Accept: "application/json",
              Authorization: `bearer ${localStorage.token}`
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ review: review }
          ),
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(( json => {
          this.setState(prevState => ({
              reviews: [...prevState.reviews, json ]
             }))
      }))
  }

//   handleShowForm = () => {
//     this.setState({edit: false})
// }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="review-grid">
               <ReviewForm addReview={this.addReview} review={this.handleSubmit} />
        <h1 className="review-content">REVIEWS!</h1>
         <ul className="review-cards">
      {
        this.state.reviews.map(review => <Review key={review.id} review={review}/>)
      }  
    </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'



class ReviewForm extends React.Component {
 
    state = {
        reviewed_game: '',
        rating: '',
        user_username: '',
    }
    
handleReviewedGame = (event) => {
    this.setState ({
        reviewed_game: event.target.value
     })
}

handleRating = (event) => {
    this.setState ({
        rating: event.target.value
     })
}

handleUser = (event) => {
    this.setState ({
        user_username: event.target.value
    })
}

handleForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // console.log(e)
    const review = {
    reviewed_game: this.state.reviewed_game,
    rating: this.state.rating,
    }
    
   this.props.addReview(review)
    }
render() {
    return (
    <div className="form-container">
            <form onSubmit={(e) => {this.handleForm(e)}}>
                <div>
                    <label>Review</label>
                    <br></br>
                    <textarea type="text" placeholder="Drop Your Review" rows={10} cols={50} value={this.state.reviewed_game} onChange={this.handleReviewedGame}  className="form"/>
                    <div>
                    <label>Stars</label>
                    <br></br>
                    <input type="number"  max="5" min="0" value={this.state.rating} onChange={this.handleRating} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="sub-review">Create Review!</button>
            </form> 
        
    </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ReviewForm;
```

Any advise on how to correct the issue is appreciated! thanks!

Comment: You want to google csrf for the first problem. The nomethod error is because you never initialize your `@user` instance variable.

Comment: Thanks for the response, how do I go about initializing this variable, is this done in my reviews_controller?